# maxlength property for itext in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, maxlength

Is there a maxlength property for itext using the fabric.js library? If not, how would one go about coding one to be as fluent and consistent as the html/javascript maxlength property? I have been working on one, but it isn't fluent like that of the maxlength property. The problem with mine is that it will add the character and then remove it, so the user can see it happen... unlike that of the maxlength property where it just stops taking input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `maxlength` to `hiddenTextarea` on text object `editing:entered` event.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
const text = new fabric.IText('Hello');
text.on('editing:entered', () => {
  text.hiddenTextarea.setAttribute('maxlength', 5);
})
canvas.add(text);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be this easy. I couldn't find the property in the documentation. Where / how did you find it? Thank you so much!

Comment: @ShanerM13 worked with this library for 2years,may b that helped. ;)